# CSS background image duplicates itself

Tags: css

I would like to know why this CSS code shows two of the same backgound image, even when I am only setting one, below is the code:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 940px; 
padding: 0 10px; 
}


/* Header */
.header {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(http://www.bolsamania.com/cine/wp-    content/uploads/2016/07/9-2.jpg);
  color: white;
  padding: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header .container {
    position: relative;
top: 200px;
}

.header h1 {
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 100px; 
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}

@media (min-width:850px) {
.header h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
}
}

.header p {
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 8px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
margin-top: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
background: #117bff;
cursor: pointer; 
transition: background .5s;  
}


/* Nav */
.nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 30px 0;
text-align: center;

}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

.nav {
  background-color: black;
}

/* Main */
.main .container {
margin: 80px auto;
}


/* Jumbotron */
.jumbotron {
height: 600px; 
text-align: right;
}

.jumbotron .container {
position: relative;
top: 220px;
}


/* Footer */
.footer { 
font-size: 14px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header h1 {
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 64px;

  }

  .main, .jumbotron {
padding: 0 30px;

  }

  .main img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main img {
  float: left;
  size: contain;
}
```

[image: As you guys can see, the image ends and starts again]

The image will repeat even when I added the:`background-repeat: no-repeat;`
Thanks in advance for the help.

You should also be able to see the HTML and CSS complete code in this link: https://gist.github.com/2bc611f755c242271cb6984a0ed11cf7

Thanks again.

Comment: Your background-repeat: no-repeat; looks to be getting overridden. Have you tried using background-image: url instead of background:url to specify your image?

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution, I just tried the bacground-image: url(); however, the issue persists. I would go with your theory of the background-repeat: no-repeat; being overriden, but I can't seem to find what is overriding it :/

Comment: Why would you add displayable markup in the <head>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some inspecting, the issue is that you have 2 "header" elements in your html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <div class=header>
    <h1>INNOVATION CLOUD</h1>
    <p>CONNECT YOUR IDEAS GLOBALLY</p>
    <a href="#" class=btn>Learn More</a>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Register</li>
        <li>Schedule</li>
        <li>Sponsor</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="container">
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <img src="http://www.themarysue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Kylo_Ren.jpg" class=kylo/>
      
      <div class="container">
        

        <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
        <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions to challenging problems.</p>
        <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most challenging projects.</p>
         <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

If you look inside your "head" element, you have an extra  that is causing the duplication. The closing  tag for that element is also right above the  div

Comment: Thanks mate! you really nailed it right on the head! I have been studying for 6 hours straight and can't see as well as you did it! Thanks, removing the duplicate header item resolved the issue. Will go to bed now....

Answer (score 4):

Where are you adding `background-repeat: no-repeat`? If you add it *before* `background` then it won't work because `background` shorthand will set it back to `repeat`. If you add it *after* it, it will.

This has bitten me a few times so I try to avoid `background` shorthand.

Comment: As you can see in the code that I added in the ´question background: url();´ is first and then i put the ´background-repeat: no-repeat;´

Comment: Sorry. Been drinking. If this is your code it'll work. Unless there's something else in your CSS touching that element it might be overriding it.

Comment: My bad.. .it is too long, I will edit the question with the whole thing..

Answer (score 0):

hi just remove the `background-size: cover;` and try the code as below

```
header {
 height: 800px;
 text-align: center;
 background: url(http://www.bolsamania.com/cine/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/9-2.jpg);
 color: white;
 padding: 100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks, I tried it without the background-size: cover; but it still shows two images, thanks for the hint tho :)

Answer (score 0):

`no-repeat` is what you need.[CSS background-repeat Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: "no-repeat" is already in the code, but it is either being overriden or not working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone happens to need it like I did and is new to this, I solved the problem in two ways and both work:

1. `background-size: cover;`
2. `background-repeat: no-repeat round;`